# Django Djoser user activation by an admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

It is there a way to override typical djoser account activation flow?
After creating an account, I would like to send activation link with uid and token to the admin and email to user eg.: "Your account will be accepted by admin withinn 48hrs or sth like that.

I would create a view with admin permissions for auth/request_activation/{uid}/{token} to handle all those requests.